# Skip preg_replace if match string is not in array

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have function which replaces strings ex. :smile: with image tag.

```
function out_emoj($str)
{

    $emoj_array = array(
        "cry", "grimacing", "joy","smiley","innocent", "wink", "flushed", "slight_smile",
        "stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye", "relaxed", "crab","cat","expressionless", "pig", "rose", "cherry_blossom",
        "sunny", "cloud_snow", "coffee","tea","grin", "ring", "crown", "nerd",
        "heart_eyes", "kissing_heart", "sunglasses","scream","rage","disappointed","fearful","confused",
        "dizzy_face", "zipper_mouth", "thermometer_face","sleeping","ghost","smiley_cat","smile_cat","joy_cat",
        "heart_eyes_cat", "smirk_cat", "kissing_cat","scream_cat","crying_cat_face","pouting_cat","thumbsup","thumbsdown",
        "angel", "dancer", "kimono","heart","purple_heart","sparkling_heart","heart_decoration","snowflake",
        );
    return preg_replace("/:(.*?):/", " <img width='22' src='".base_url('assets/img/emojiones/$1.png')."' alt='$1'> ", $str);
}
```

I want to check if the match string is in array and then replace else skip.
ex: if user inputs  :notfound: function will add tag with image which not exists. I want to check if "notfound" is in array first.

Comment: Take a look at: `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: Why dont you use a simple loop ? Pregmatch is a total overkill in this case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prince Actarus, you can add `preg_replace_callback` to your golgot weapons:

```
return preg_replace_callback("/:(.*?):/", function ($m) use ($emoj_array) {
    if (in_array($m[1], $emoj_array))
        return ' <img width="22" src="' . base_url('assets/img/emojiones/' . $m[1] . '.png') . '" alt="' . $m[1] . '"> ';
    return $m[0];
}, $str);
```

Another way consists to build an array of patterns mapping your original array and to use `preg_replace`, but it's less efficient since your string will be parsed once per pattern.

---

Other way: build an alternation:

```
$pattern = '/:(' . implode('|', $emoj_array) . '):/';

return preg_replace($pattern, ' <img width="22" src="' . base_url('assets/img/emojiones') . '/$1.png" alt="$1"> ', $str);
```

Comment: good answer. now i know that if i want use global variable inside function i can use "use (array)".

Answer (score 0):

```
function out_emoj($str)
{
    $emoj_array = array(
        "cry", "grimacing", "joy","smiley","innocent", "wink", "flushed", "slight_smile",
        "stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye", "relaxed", "crab","cat","expressionless", "pig", "rose", "cherry_blossom",
        "sunny", "cloud_snow", "coffee","tea","grin", "ring", "crown", "nerd",
        "heart_eyes", "kissing_heart", "sunglasses","scream","rage","disappointed","fearful","confused",
        "dizzy_face", "zipper_mouth", "thermometer_face","sleeping","ghost","smiley_cat","smile_cat","joy_cat",
        "heart_eyes_cat", "smirk_cat", "kissing_cat","scream_cat","crying_cat_face","pouting_cat","thumbsup","thumbsdown",
        "angel", "dancer", "kimono","heart","purple_heart","sparkling_heart","heart_decoration","snowflake",
        );

    return preg_replace_callback("/:(.*?):/",
        function($m) use ($emoj_array)
        {

            if (in_array($m[1],$emoj_array))
            {
                return " <img width='22' src='".base_url('assets/img/emojiones/'.$m[1].'.png')."' alt='{$m[1]}'> ";
            }
            else
            {
                return ':'.$m[1].':';
            }
        } 
     , $str);

}
```

thank you @Casimir et Hippolyte and @rizier123  here is my solution

Comment: `str_replace` is useless, since what you want is already in `$m[1]` *(first capturing group)*.

Comment: thnx @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: just perfect. i will use your second version of code.